# passing "this" to a this() or super()

Tags: java

My questions is this:

Why can I not pass `this` to an explicit call to a constructor?

Example:

```
class MyClass {

    MyClass x;

    public MyClass(MyClass c) {
        x = c;
    }

    public MyClass() {
        this(this);        // Error
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very confusing to start a question with "because". What do you want to do?

Comment: I don't think that is a question?

Comment: I must not do anything, just let me know why this thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass a reference to `this` from a constructor to another constructor on the same instance.

In Java you cannot access `this` implicitly or explicitly in the constructor before returning from an implicit or explicit call to `this()` or `super()`. This is because the super class has not yet initialised.

You may need to duplicate code in the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    private final MyClass myInstance;
    public MyClass(MyClass myInstance) {
        this.myInstance = myInstance;
    }
    public MyClass() {
        this.myInstance = this;
    }
}
```

There may be ways to hack around it using a private constructor, but then you are into hacking territory.

Comment: Shouldn't `this.myInstance = null;` be `this.myInstance = this;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work around to this restriction.

The work around is to pass a temporary holder object to the super class constructor.  Then after the super class constructor has done its work, give the temporary holder object a reference to this.

The parameter delta can be used to show the principal shortcoming of this workaround - what if the superclass constructor needs to use the parameter.

```
import java . lang . reflect . * ;
import java . util . * ;

class Father
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
         ( new Son ( args . length > 0 ) ) . run ( ) ;
    }

    Father ( Runnable runnable , boolean delta )
    {
         super ( ) ;
         if ( delta )
         {
        runnable . run ( ) ;
         }
    }
}

class Son extends Father implements Runnable
{
    private static Map < Thread , TempRunnable > temps = new HashMap < Thread , TempRunnable > ( ) ;

    private static class TempRunnable implements Runnable
    {
         private Son son ;

         TempRunnable ( )
         {
             super ( ) ;
             temps . put ( Thread . currentThread ( ) , this ) ;
         }

         public void run ( )
         {
             son . run ( ) ;
         }
    }

    Son ( boolean delta )
    {
         // super ( this ) ; // the dream
         super ( new TempRunnable ( ) , delta ) ;
         temps . get ( Thread . currentThread ( ) ) . son = this ;
    }

    public void run ( )
    {
         System . out . println ( "Hello World" ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, You could assign `this` to `x` as the default value when you pass `null` to the constructor.

```
class MyClass {
    
   final MyClass x;
   
   public MyClass(MyClass c){
       x = c == null ? this : c;
   }

   public MyClass(){
       this(null);
   }

}
```